# Can't import "import com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have a question about the FirestoreRecyclerOptions : 
The FirestoreRecyclerOptions cannot import

> com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges

When I compile my program I have the following error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/MetadataChanges

I think it's a version problem in the gradle. Do you know how to fix this?

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.0'
//Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1'
// FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.1'
```

The function when i call the recycleroption

```
 private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<chat> generateOptionsForAdapter(Query query){

    return new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<chat>()
            .setQuery(query,chat.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();

}
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: I have the error here ".setQuery()"